# Github for Windows puts repo in "rebasing" state, but says "failed to sync this branch"

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

Sometimes when I press the `Sync` button on Github for Windows, it tells me:

```
Failed to sync this branch
You might need to open a shell and debug the state of this repo
```

I then go to the console and enter a `git status`. Most of the time when this happens, `git status` tells me the following info:

```
> git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

You are currently rebasing.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

If I understand that correctly, then:

- Github for Windows started a Rebase operation, but did not succeed for whatever reason.
- The working copy is clean. There are no changed files that could be overwritten by the Sync, and there are no conflicts either.
- Git tells me to continue the rebase operation once all conflicts are resolved (although in this case, there are no conflicts).

`> git rebase --continue`

`Stray path/to/repo/.git/rebase-apply directory found.`

`Use "git am --abort" to remove it.`

I do that:

```
> git am --abort
```

After that, the Rebase operation is finished/aborted, and pressing the Github for Windows' Sync button again successfully pushes the commits.

**I'm just wondering, if there are no conflicts, why does the Sync op fail in the first place?**

Comment: Also check whether **Github is down**? This happened to me today. Check status at https://status.github.com/messages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm one of the GitHub for Windows developers.

There's a log file that GitHub for Windows generates that will help understand what was occurring at the time of doing the sync:

https://help.github.com/articles/accessing-the-github-for-windows-log

I'd love to see why the rebase is failing, because it looks like it all *should* be completing judging by the other details...

Comment: Gonna do that the next time it happens. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Sync op fail in the first place?

Because the GUI doesn't want to silently complete the rebase, and wants to make sure the user is aware of said rebase.

Comment: But sometimes it silently completes the rebase. I want to know the circumstances that lead to the 'failed sync'.